# Repainting container in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am working on Creating some objects in a container withing a from in codenameone. I am moving objects every 2 seconds, the objects are moving but the container is unable to display the objects. It displays only when i click the sidemenubar and it shows objects on the container. If SideMenuBar is closed , it again disappears.
I am posting 2 images which describes the problem.
I used repaint(), revalidate() and also show() but it is showing the same thing. Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you are doing but I guess you just paint the green background on top of these images that you draw at some point. The side menu bar converts the form to a screenshot when sliding out so you are seeing a frozen state of the form not the actual view.

Comment: So What you are trying to say is Background Color is hiding the objects? If I remove the Background Color also, am unable to see the objects,

Comment: The Images attached are part of my project. But the Basic thing what am trying to do is I just want to display those objects on the container. As I can see from the Console that the location of objects are changing and also the Objects are drawn but am unable to see it. I am not sure what is the problem is. I tried to repaint it and also revalidate it , but no Success yet.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is the background painting is hiding the objects for some reason. The question is how did you paint and what you did exactly. I'm guessing you used transforms without properly restoring the affine.